# In an object, there are 2 objects. How do I merge these 2 objects together?

Tags: javascript

```
obj = {
{id: 1, name: Jane},
{id: 2, name: Lim}
}
```

How do I get the desired output of
['Jane', 'Lim']

This is the following methods I have tried but none of them work:

1. merge()
2. obj.map(ob => ob.name)

Comment: #2 should've work... if it was an array. Is `obj` in this example really an object?  What are the keys then? Regardless, [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) might help you in this case so you get an array from object.

Comment: @captainskippah the obj here holds 2 objects when it returned

Comment: object and array is different. object has keys/properties e.g `id` key has value of `1` in your example. If it really was **object** of object instead of **array** of objects, then use `Object.values()` as mentioned to get an array then your #2 should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = {
  {id: 1, name: Jane},
  {id: 2, name: Lim}
}
```

That is not a valid javascript object, where is the data coming from?

If you are creating it, it should look like this:

```
const obj = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Jane' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Lim' },
      ]
```

Then you can use array methods as you are expecting: `obj.map((object) => object.name)`

Otherwise you get `SyntaxError`